# How to match specific year range with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find in string specific year range between 2007-2009.
How can i do it with regex?

This what i trued so far, but not really understand, how it should look like.

```
/^(200[7-9]|20[7-9]\d|200\d|200[7-9])$/
```

Comment: No need using anchors if you need to extract substrings from a larger string. Use `/\b200[7-9]\b/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/200[7-9]/g` should be enough for matching a date in that range anywhere in a string.

Your example would also match some incorrect values, like 201, 2011, 2001.

Comment: Thank You, for your answer.

Comment: You don't need the `g` flag.

Comment: Good point. You can omit the /g flag if you're only searching for a single occurrence.